# Postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, syntax

I am having a problem creating a function that will take 2 inputs (startDate and endDate) and it will return all the results between those dates. I think syntax is my main problem. The dates I am currently using is just for testing purpose. How can I do it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report_new(stDt date, endDt date) 
RETURNS TABLE("Form" integer, "CBID" character varying(4000),"Drug Duration" character varying(4000),"DateNotify" character varying(4000),"Dose" character varying(4000),
"Agent" character varying(4000),"Onset" character varying(4000),"Expectedness" character varying(4000),
"Grade" character varying(4000),"Investigator's opinion" character varying(4000),"Protocol No." character varying(4000), 
"Medical Monitor's Opinion" character varying(4000),"Status" character varying(4000),"Offset" character varying(4000),
"Reported Term" character varying(4000),"Why Serious" character varying(4000),"Study No." character varying(4000),"Subject No." character varying(4000))

AS
$BODY$

SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB(
'SELECT event_crf_id, i.description, id.value FROM item i, item_data id 
WHERE i.item_id=id.item_id 
AND id.item_id IN (select item_id from item_data where event_crf_id  IN   (select event_crf_id from event_crf where crf_version_id=88)
AND name SIMILAR TO ''(SAE_SPONSSTDYNO|SAE_STUDYSUBJNO|SAE_IRBPROTNO|SAE_DRGUNINV|SAE_DOSEEVENT|SAE_GRADE|SAE_REPTERM|SAE_EVENTSTART|SAE_EXPOCCSA|SAE_OUTCOME_DAT|SAE_OUTCOME_STATUS|SAE_MM_OPN_REL|SAE_MONOPSER|SAE_EXP|SAE_RESULTDEATH|SAE_CBID|SAE_DTLTRSNT)'') 
AND ''id.date_created between '''||to_char(stDt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''' AND '''||to_char(endDt, 'YYYY-MM-DD')'''ORDER BY 1,2') 
AS ct ("Form" integer, "CBID" character varying(4000),"Drug Duration" character varying(4000),"DateNotify" character varying(4000),"Dose" character varying(4000),
"Agent" character varying(4000),"Onset" character varying(4000),"Expectedness" character varying(4000),
"Grade" character varying(4000),"Investigator's opinion" character varying(4000),"Protocol No." character varying(4000), 
"Medical Monitor's Opinion" character varying(4000),"Status" character varying(4000),"Offset" character varying(4000),
"Reported Term" character varying(4000),"Why Serious" character varying(4000),"Study No." character varying(4000),"Subject No." character varying(4000))

$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;
```

Comment: I'm a little lost . . . What does the question in the first paragraph have to do with the query in the posting?

Comment: Google for postgresql function returning setof or table - you will find tons of examples

Comment: I think you are looking for the [`format()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) (like in `format('SELECT ... WHERE id.date_created between %L and %L', param1, param2)`)

Comment: I previously posted the query that I want to use in the function. I tried  creating the function but it gives me errors.

Comment: @pozs neat! `format()` new in 9.1 as an alternative to `quote_nullable()`, `quote_ident()`, I should spend more time reading changelogs,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by actually splitting up everything. Created a function that generate the overall data, and then created another function that would call the previous one and narrow down the results according to the date selection, so  on and so forth...

I will update with the full code later, maybe it will help someone else :)